# copy NSMutableArray atIndex (0) to other NSMutable index (0)

Tags: iphone, arrays, copy, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i have 2 array
1st array if full
2nd array is empty
i want to copy only 1st array value at index 0 to 2nd array at index 0

is it possible?

thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`secondArrayValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:ArrayValue copyItems:YES];`

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

`[array2 insertObject: [array1 objectAtIndex: 0u] atIndex: 0u]`

Comment: It means that an integer is unsigned. If this answer worked for you, please click the √ next to it.

Comment: [secondArrayValue insertObject:[ArrayValue objectAtIndex:0] AtIndex : 0];---i tried as u said --but its not working

Comment: `array2` needs to be an instance of `NSMutableArray` otherwise it won't work.